# Site in Azure Websites fails processing of X509Certificate2

Tags: c#, azure, azure-web-app-service, x509certificate2

I have site in Azure Websites (not Hosted Service) and I need processing .pfx certificates with private key there.

```
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate, password);
```

But I was faced with follow exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

In article http://blog.tylerdoerksen.com/2013/08/23/pfx-certificate-files-and-windows-azure-websites/ I have found that it happens because by default the system uses a local directory of user to store the key. But Azure Websites have no local user profile directory. In the same article author propose to use `X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet` flag.

```
var x509Certificate2 = new X509Certificate2(certificate, password, X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
```

But now I have other exception:

```
System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: Access denied.

   at System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException.ThrowCryptographicException(Int32 hr)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Utils._LoadCertFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, IntPtr password, UInt32 dwFlags, Boolean persistKeySet, SafeCertContextHandle& pCertCtx)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.LoadCertificateFromBlob(Byte[] rawData, Object password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2..ctor(Byte[] rawData, String password, X509KeyStorageFlags keyStorageFlags)
```

Can anybody help me to understand why it happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 98, accepted):

I guess you found a workaround, but if others are struggling with this, I found the answer to this in another SO question:

[How can constructing an X509Certificate2 from a PKCS#12 byte array throw CryptographicException("The system cannot find the file specified.")?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3826321/how-can-constructing-an-x509certificate2-from-a-pkcs12-byte-array-throw-cryptog)

The magic is specifying the X509KeyStorageFlags storage flags. Example:

```
var myCertificae = new X509Certificate2(
    certificateData,
    securePasswordString,
    X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | 
    X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
```

Comment: Thank you. This helped me within a webjob instance too. I was receiving error: Job failed due to exit code -1073740940

Comment: This is the only search result that came up for this error number 1073740940. There was no error attached when I was running it as a webjob just that exist code. Thanks a lot @ThomasEdmondson that was driving me nuts.

Comment: This did the trick for me on an Azure Web App, thanks! It should probably be the accepted answer.

Comment: This should be the answer

Comment: This used to work for me a few months ago - but ever since I started a new Azure Website today I'm getting the same error, except I *am* specifying all three `X509KeyStorageFlags` values. I wonder if there's a change in Azure's configuration.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Why is this necessary anyway?

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: This cured my problem too. I was getting Win32Exception (0x8009030D): The credentials supplied to the package were not recognised. This is called from within PushSharp's AuthenticateClient on an SSL Stream when connecting to APNS. Thank you kindly.

Comment: Are there security implications to using a machine-wide store for an azure web app?

Comment: BTW: You can pass in a null for securePasswordString.  I was pulling a full PPK Cert from Azure KeyVault which gives me a cer=byte[], but no password.  This worked for me.

Comment: This is the proper answer

Comment: I could pass an empty string for the password.  Passing null would not work because that leads to an ambiguous overload error.

Answer (score 6):

Azure Websites now has native support for installing certificates to the certificate store.  Have you given that a shot?

Details here: http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/10/27/using-certificates-in-azure-websites-applications/

Comment: That link just saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Works like a charm

Comment: The section to manage web sites in the old portal has ben deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by following the instructions from [the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code#make-the-certificate-accessible). Not sure if this was an option before, but now it is, and it was easy to use / implement.

1. First I uploaded the .pfx certificate to my Azure App Service and entered the password when asked to enter it. Copied the thumbprint.
2. Then I ran the following command from inside Azure Console (I only added a single thumbprint). This is important as it enables your app to access the cert:

```sh
az webapp config appsettings set --name <app-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --settings WEBSITE_LOAD_CERTIFICATES=<comma-separated-certificate-thumbprints>
```

3. I used the following method to load the previously uploaded .pfx certificate into my app:

```cs
public X509Certificate2 GetAzureCertificate(string thumbprint, bool validOnly)
{
    using (var certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser))
    {
        certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, validOnly);
        var cert = certCollection.OfType<X509Certificate2>().FirstOrDefault();

        if (cert == null)
        {
            throw new Exception($"Cert not found. Total cert count : {certStore.Certificates.Count}.");
        }

        return cert;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Azure Websites run in a shared environment. I am assuming that the constructor for the certificate is attempting to create some temporary information on the instance and it does not have permission to.
You may have to upgrade to a hosted service in order to run in an elevated context and perform this work.
Also, have you validated that the password is correct? If it doesn't require a password, you at least have to pass string.Empty to the constructor. Passing in a NULL value would also cause this exception.

Comment: Our search for solutions had no success. So, we moved our application to Hosted Services.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, and struggled many hours for fixing it. 
In the article that you mention the last stack call is to the function *LoadCertFromFile*, but in your (and my) case it is *LoadCertFromBlob*.

So I looked for LoadCertFromBlob and found this:

[Why does X509Certificate2 sometimes fail to create from a blob?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/558423/why-does-x509certificate2-sometimes-fail-to-create-from-a-blob)

The solution was to go in IIS and change the application pool identity from "ApplicationPoolIdentity" to "LocalService", so that the certificate is loaded in right local folder.

Comment: No, I do not load cert from blobs, I load it from byte array.
Yes, you are right, the problem is in the access permissions of the application pool identity. But I deploy my application in Azure Websites. I cannot change IIS the application pool identity there. So, I moved it to Hosted Services.

Comment: I was talking about the "_LoadCertFromBlob" call in the exception that you report.

Comment: Or you can stick with application identity, but turn `Load User Profile` to true.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure Websites / Web App / Mobile App - you have to use App Service Plan that allwos you to import SSL certificate - so it shoud not be a Free or Shared. You can import not only SSL certificate, but also for an example code signing cerificate and use it in signtool or from PowerShell.

I used this method in https://vmplace.eu/

If you try to use a Free or Shared plan you receive error - so in Azure in these Plans there is other version of .NET framework.

You can refer to this project also: https://github.com/onovotny/SignService

## mvpbuzz