# WindowsCryptographicException running ASP.NET Core 2 web app in Azure Web App Service

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to host a ASP.NET Core 2 web application using Azure's Web App Service. The web app runs fine on my development machine (Windows 10). It also works on a Ubuntu 17.10 virtual machine when I publish the files. However, when I publish the web app from Visual Studio to Azure I get the following error message:

```
WindowsCryptographicException: The system cannot find the file specified
    System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(string keyName, CngProvider provider, CngKeyOpenOptions openOptions)
    System.Security.Cryptography.CngKey.Open(string keyName, CngProvider provider)
    Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey<T>(Func<CspParameters, T> createCsp, Func<CngKey, T> createCng)
    Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
    Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey<T>(X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate<X509Certificate2> matchesConstraints)
    ...
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.IISSetupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder app)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.AutoRequestServicesStartupFilter+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Configure>b__0(IApplicationBuilder builder)
    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
.NET Core 4.6.26212.01 X86 v4.0.0.0    |   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting version 2.0.2-rtm-10011    |    Microsoft Windows 10.0.14393
```

I am storing a key file in the project directory and attempting to create credentials from it.

After searching, I have found the following sites that point to similar solutions:
https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11042, https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/issues/1432, [Certificate not found when deploying IdentityServer 4 to Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44643663), and [CryptographicException was unhandled: System cannot find the specified file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17840825/9779417)

These suggest that I need to modify the settings of the Application Pool and set the "Load User Profile" to true and properly set the permissions of the file. However, I am unsure of how to do this using the [Azure Portal](https://portal.azure.com).

In addition, instead of modifying a file on the server, is there a solution where code can be added to either Program.cs or Startup.cs (excerpts given below)?

Program.cs ([referenced link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41915522/asp-net-core-1-1-runs-fine-locally-but-when-publishing-to-azure-says-an-error-o))

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        BuildWebHost(args).Run();
    }

    public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
        WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseSetting("detailedErrors", "true")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .CaptureStartupErrors(true)
            .Build();
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {   
        services.AddMvc();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseBrowserLink();
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Update #1**

The app deploys properly. I just encounter the error when the following code is executed.

```
private static RSA GetPrivateKey(byte[] p12) {
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    return rsa;
}
```

Here is my project .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="GDataDB" Version="1.0.0" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.8" />
        <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.3" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Folder Include="Pages\" />
        <Folder Include="Properties\PublishProfiles\" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Update="total-method-203123-88f147135d99.p12">
            <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
        </None>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Udpate #2**

Here is a minimal repo that demonstrates the error: https://github.com/jonliew/testdatawebapp

I first publish the GDataDB to a nuget package using the FolderProfile in Visual Studio. Then, I add the package to the DataWebApp project. Finally, I publish the DataWebApp and get the above behavior.

Comment: take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27146917/1831108

Comment: I tried setting the X509KeyStorageFlags to no avail. The other solutions suggest that I need to load the user profile, which I am unsure about.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the issue is that you are targeting .NET Core 2.0.8, which is not yet fully deployed on App Service. See [here](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/107) for the announcement.

To verify whether this is indeed the problem, please try deploying to a test Web App in the **West US 2** region (*not* West US), which does have the release. You should not get the error there.

Comment: I believe that I am targeting .NET Core 2.0.7, since that is the version of Microsoft.AspNetCore.All my project is using. I tried to deploy to the West US 2 region in a new resource group and I got the same error.
The app deploys properly; it only encounters the error when the following code is executed:
    private static RSA GetPrivateKey(byte[] p12) {
    var certificate = new X509Certificate2(p12, "notasecret", X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable);
    var rsa = certificate.GetRSAPrivateKey();
    return rsa;
    }

Comment: That's odd. As a test, does it work in West US 2 if you instead target 2.0.8?

Comment: I made an edit to my above comment after you replied. If updating the Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package to 2.0.8 targets .NET Core 2.0.8, then deploying a 2.0.8 to West US 2 does not help. 
I included both the code in my above comment and my .csproj in Update #1.

Comment: Can you please [share a minimal repo](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Using-a-git-repo-to-report-an-issue) the demonstrates the issue? It will help us investigate. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a link to a minimal repo: https://github.com/jonliew/testdatawebapp
My update in the original post describes how I build it.

Comment: Just noticed your comment about user profile. Try setting `WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE=1` in the App Settings in the Portal. See [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#add-user-profile-support-for-a-site) for more info.

Comment: Unfortunately, I am operating on the Free tier so this setting is not available. I managed to get my web app running on Heroku using Docker.